# Background Thread in Python Interpreter Suspends on time.sleep()

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

We have built a custom python interpreter, and are trying to create a function to kick off a background thread that periodically calls a function to get a sensor reading, and then store that reading inside a circular buffer (implemented using a `deque` with a maximum length).

Below shows a cut-down version of our implementation. The problem we are facing is that, when we call `monitor_sensor()` from the interpreter to begin the background thread, the code in the background thread appears to only get executed once (which we determined by looking at the contents of `sensor_values`). Also, when we try to exit the interpreter (using `exit()`) the interpreter hangs and never exits.

```
import code
import collections
import threading

def get_sensor_reading():
    return 5.0

sensor_values = {}

def monitor_sensor():
    sensor_values['sensor_1'] = collections.deque(maxlen=1000)
    background_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_monitor_sensor, args=[sensor_values, get_sensor_reading])
    background_thread.start()

def run_monitor_sensor(sensor_values, read_sensor_cmd):
    while True:
        reading = read_sensor_cmd()
        sensor_values['sensor_1'].append(reading)
        import time
        time.sleep(1)

imported_objects = {'monitor_sensor': monitor_sensor,
                    'sensor_values': sensor_values}

code.interact(local=imported_objects)
```

Below shows a dump of the interpreter session where we try to run the background thread and look at the data stored - note that we are waiting far longer than the 1 second sleep between attempts to read the values in `sensor_values`.

```
218> python manage.py example
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> monitor_sensor()
>>> sensor_values
{'sensor_1': deque([5.0], maxlen=1000)}
>>> sensor_values
{'sensor_1': deque([5.0], maxlen=1000)}
```

The issue looks to be with the call to `time.sleep(1)` - if we remove this then the buffer will quickly fill up with values. Can anyone tell us why this problem occurs, and how we can work around it?

**Update**

We have solved the problem by moving `import time` from inside the loop to the module level. No clue thus far *why* this fixes the issue but if anyone can answer this then will accept that answer.

Comment: This isn't your problem, but… why would you `import time` in the middle of a loop?

Comment: Anyway, the reason `exit` hangs is that the program won't terminate until all (non-daemon) threads do, and `exit` just terminates the main thread. You have to stop (or daemonize) the background thread.

Comment: Also, if you want to know how many times the background loop is running, instead of trying to guess, why not just have it do something like `sys.stderr.write('.'); sys.stderr.flush()` each time through the loop? If it stalls, it'll be pretty hard to miss.

Comment: Reply to first comment: When we were first putting this together, and imported time at the module level, there appeared to be an issue calling time.sleep() from inside the loop (error was reported that 'cannot find time' or something along those lines). This is a relic of that, will see if the import inside the loop can be removed.

Comment: Reply to second comment: That's good to know thanks - we actually resolved this by using `thread.start_new_thread` instead of creating and starting a `threading.Thread`.

Comment: Just moving `import time` to the top level cannot possibly have solved any problem. Most likely it's just adding a delay that makes some race condition less likely. This means that, instead of failing every time, your app will fail just often enough to be unusable in practice and not often enough to be easy to debug. (The same is true with replacing `threading.Thread` with `thread.start_new_thread`.) This kind of "shotgun debugging" is always bad, but it's _especially_ bad when you're dealing with threading bugs, because they're so hard to reproduce if you don't understand them.

Answer (score 1):

You're sharing a mutable value between two threads without a lock.

This isn't actually *guaranteed* to be a problem in Python, and it may not be your problem… but it's definitely wrong, and it *can* cause problems like this.

To fix it, do something like this:

```
sensor_values = {}
sensor_lock = threading.Lock()

def monitor_sensor():
    sensor_values['sensor_1'] = collections.deque(maxlen=1000)
    background_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_monitor_sensor, args=[sensor_values, get_sensor_reading, sensor_lock])
    background_thread.start()

def run_monitor_sensor(sensor_values, read_sensor_cmd, sensor_lock):
    while True:
        reading = read_sensor_cmd()
        with sensor_lock:
            sensor_values['sensor_1'].append(reading)
        import time
        time.sleep(1)

def get_sensor_values():
    with sensor_lock:
        return sensor_values
```

Comment: Thanks - yer we figured that this wasn't gonna be thread safe (this is very much a first draft) however it didn't appear to be the root of the problem. Really appreciate the guide to locking you saved we have applied the upgrade!